# How to adjust the location of lightning-helptext

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, helptext

I want to move the sf logo (tooltip) 2-3 pixels up so I tried to add custom CSS such as margin-bottom or padding-bottom to the element but it doesn't move.
[image: Demonstration]

Couldn't find anything relevant in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-helptext/documentation), and I really prefer to use this element out-of-the-box and not to create one myself using SLDS.

[Demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fDlubbrBW/1/edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF you Just want to move the SF logo you can try this

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-text-body_small">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
       <span style="position:relative; top:-2px;"> <lightning-helptext icon-name="utility:salesforce1" content="Click the icon"></lightning-helptext></span>
    </div>
</template>
```

there could be multiple other ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fDlubbrBW/4/edit)

Basically, wrapping the element in a span and adding css to the span element

Comment: Link seems to have broken